# Automated phone calls

Tags: voip, telephony, phone-call

I'm working on a website which uses certain courier company for shipping. The problem with them is that they require a phone call and then typing in the customer number to request a courier pickup.

I was wondering if there's a way it can be automated by using some online service to initiate that call and dial the numbers.

So, to reiterate: service should allow to dial a number and then dial a number sequence after connect, then hang up.

Does anyone have an idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: Its not very much clear what are you looking for. check http://public.ifbyphone.com/ if it gives you any pointer

Comment: I've updated a question a little bit. ifbyphone may be able to do it, i'll have a look, thanks

Comment: I don't know of an online service that does this, but you can do it with a plain modem and phone line using DTMF tones.

Answer (score 2):

You can automate outbound calls using a platform that supports the W3C standards [Call Control XML (CCXML)](http://www.w3.org/TR/ccxml/) and [VoiceXML](http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml20/). You use the CCXML to initiate the call and perform call progress analysis so that when the call is answered it can be passed to a VoiceXML application which would play the DTMF back as recorded audio.  You can use [Voxeo Prophecy](http://evolution.voxeo.com/) as the platform to run the CCXML and VoiceXML.  You can get a two port version for free that you can run on your workstation or you can test for free on their hosted environment. Look at their [CCXML documentation](http://docs.voxeo.com/ccxml/1.0-final/) for examples on how to develop Outbound Dialers in Section F. You can get [recorded DTMF tones in audio files here](http://evolution.voxeo.com/library/audio/prompts/dtmf/index.jsp) that will run on this platform.

Comment: That is an interesting option, i'll investigate. A lot to learn.